# How to make this with css or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my first time asking a question on this platform so I'm no virgin anymore.

As you can see in the image:

[image: Example image]

I want the green triangle on each side to be responsive so they always cross each other in the middle no matter the size of the screen.

I came up with making a square rotating it and giving it a `height: 100%;` and `width 100%vh` so the block has the same height and width. But this didn't work I also tried a couple of other things but none of them seemed to work.

I hope that one of you guys can point me in the right direction. (Maybe using javascript and css combined)

Comment: Post your code and we'll start from there.

Comment: First you should try to achieve a little on your own. Your right they need to have height: 100% and witdth:50% on need to be placed absolute on the left the other on the right. How to create the form you can read here: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: We can't deduce your markup based on screenshot alone: it helps to post your markup and CSS (even if it doesn't work!), because it will stop the community from wasting time writing a solution that can't be used later because of some small technicalities. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create that effect simply by using an SVG as a background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="2" height="2">
    <g style="fill:rgb(89, 138, 132)">
        <path d="M0 0L0 2L1 1Z" />
        <path d="M2 0L2 2L1 1Z" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

```css
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; 
    background-image: url(/* svg */);
}
```

Detailed version: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/eo29ydtt/
Data URL version: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/68t0h9g5/

An SVG image works great because it is scalable and does not require new `vw`/`wh` units. It is also easy to understand and without border magics. The SVG image needs not be a separate file, it can be created on the go as in the fiddle or include a base64 dataURL of the file directly in the CSS. The appropriate dimension and offset are also calculated by the browser, which can be heavily optimized. Unlike the answer by *rblarsen*, this method can create any other arbitrary shapes and the ratio remains the same.

Comment: *The SVG image needs not be a separate file* Well technically yes, what you do in the fiddle is *creating a new File*. IMO it might even have been a good idea to show that a dataURI version of this svg file can be embedded directly in the CSS file.

Comment: @Kaiido A base64 encoding also works (and should be done instead of creating a blob!), but this way I can demonstrate the actual SVG content to OP.

Comment: You could have added it as a comment node in your fiddle. Also, no need to b64 encode the dataURI, plain-text can do as well (as long as you encode special characters like `=` and `#`)

Comment: I'm sure OP can figure out the details on his own. This is merely a starting point for him to expand upon.

Comment: Yes sure, I forgot OP since second sentence of my first comment u_u

Comment: Thank  you @Derek朕會功夫 for providing this solution it works great :). I will add my code next time even if it doesn't work thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 4):

Remember to post your code, so we have something to work from.

That said, heres how I would make your design: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krqede4L/)

HTML:

```
<div class="image--triangles"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.image--triangles {
    background-image:url('http://via.placeholder.com/1500x1500');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.image--triangles::before {
    content: "";
    display:block;
    border: 50vh solid transparent;
    border-left: 50vw solid green;
    border-right: 50vw solid green;
}
```

**EDIT:**
To make the triangles start inside the container you can add a wrapper around, with same color as the border, and set a specified width for the image--triangles and centering it:

HTML:

```
<div class="image--triangles_wrap">
    <div class="image--triangles"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image--triangles_wrap {
    background-color:green;
}
.image--triangles {
    background-image:url('http://via.placeholder.com/1500x1500');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width:80vw;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.image--triangles::before {
    content: "";
    display:block;
    border: 50vh solid transparent;
    border-left: 40vw solid green;
    border-right: 40vw solid green;
}
```

Comment: If you look closely at the given design, side triangles starts a bit off of the container (assuming that what we see is only the container)

Comment: Oh right, I just saw that, now you mention it - I have updated my answer to correct for that.

Comment: @rblarsen Thank you for your answer i will post some code next time sorry for this and thanks for pointing it out.